# Make a sliding div stop when reaches end of post div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a floating box on the side of my post. This is the code of the post div

```
 <div class="post-entry>
    <div class="float-div">
       data 
    </div>
  divs and text
 </div>
```

And this is the javascript code that make it to move with a nice effect

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(function() {
 var offset = $(".float-div").offset();
 var topPadding = 100;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
         $(".float-div").stop().animate({
             marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
         });
     } else {
         $(".float-div").stop().animate({
             marginTop: 7
         });
       };
    });
  });
 </script>
```

The problem is that it moves thorough the whole page all the way until the footer. But it needs to stop at the end of the div "post-entry". Any ideas on how to make it stop?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to work with yours [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Kjc6k/2/)**

The following will scroll to a footer, but can be modified to scroll where need be.

```
var $scrollingDiv = $(".float-div");

$(window).scroll(function(){      
    var y = $(this).scrollTop(),
        $postEntry = $('.post-entry'),
        maxY = $postEntry.offset().top + $postEntry.height(),
        scrollHeight = $scrollingDiv.height();
    if(y< maxY-scrollHeight ){
        $scrollingDiv
        .stop()
        .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"}, "slow" );        
    }    
});
```

Possibly a duplicate of [Jquery Scrolling div - Prevent from entering site footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123153/jquery-scrolling-div-prevent-from-entering-site-footer/5123330#5123330) if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Im not sure how implement it in my script

Comment: @Jim I updated the code to work with yours in the link. *updated again in case you have elements above etc.*

Comment: Thank you for your help but with your code there are some problems
1. If i scroll down and then up the float-div appears higher
2. It stops in the middle of the next div

Comment: @Jim if you could post a bit more of your markup I could help you out more.